# submit form on 'enter' in IE "web browser"

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

having a problem with the number one browser for downloading another browser...IE

IE8 fails to submit when you hit enter in a form. here is what i use:

```
function submitOnEnter() {
    if (browserName=="Microsoft Internet Explorer")
    {
        var key;

        if (window.event){
            key = window.event.keyCode; //IE
        }

        if(key == 13){
          document.forms['myform'].submit();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is located on the text input :

```
 onkeyup="submitOnEnter()"
```

The form seems to submit when i press enter twice?? but not once.

Can you help?

Comment: Could you show the form mark-up? The enter key should work, even in IE.

Comment: IE*... the latest public release. Im pretty sure the enter key doesnt work in IE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay guys, i fixed it using....

```
  <!-- Fix for IE bug (One text input and submit, disables submit on pressing "Enter") -->    
  <div style="display:none">                 
  <input type="text" name="hiddenText"/>     
  </div>
```

Weird eh? Maybe this will work for some of you and not others. some solutions didnt work for me, this one did.

Answer (score 3):

Submit works when pressing ENTER when there is a submit button present in the form `<input type="submit">`. You can hide the button if you want. No need to intercept keystrokes.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that i checked for the submit button. But IE seems not to send the submits in the $_POST array. Adding a hidden field solved my problem.

Comment: What hidden field did you add and where?